# getting and seting the value of TextInput onPress of Button in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to get the value of text input, then create a new post with the text provided, but I get the error that

```
Argument of type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

which, is related to the line createNewPost(TextInputValue). I am not sure how to retrieve the Text Only, instead of the actual event.

```
      <View style = {{flexDirection: "row"}}> 


            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                value = {input}
            />

            <Button
                onPress={TextInputValue => createNewPost(TextInputValue)}
                title="Add post"
                color="blue"
                accessibilityLabel="A button to allow the admin to create a new post"
            />

     </View>
```

Comment: Do you have the value in state, because the way you are using onpress is wrong and i dont see the text input value being maintained in state

Comment: I have   const [input, setInput] = React.useState('Default Text');

Comment: I am not sure where I need to set the state, and even if I did, how would I call my createNewPost function

Comment: You can check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the textinput value in the state and use in the button press like below.

```
 <View style = {{flexDirection: "row"}}> 

        <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
            value = {input}
            onChangeText={text=>setInput(text)}
        />

        <Button
            onPress={()=> createNewPost(input)}
            title="Add post"
            color="blue"
            accessibilityLabel="A button to allow the admin to create a new post"
        />

 </View>
```